Volume of shape under rotation

If we were to find the volume of the shape after the shaded area rotates $360$ degrees on the $x-$axis, does it mean the volume equals half of the semisphere since they have the exact location? I obtained two different answers using different methods, and nothing seemed to go wrong.
First method:
The volume of the shape should be half of the hemisphere, thus
$$\frac{1}{2}\pi\int_0^\sqrt{8} (8-x^2)\ \mathrm dx=23.695 \text{ unit}^3$$
Second method:
Divide the shaded region into a triangle and a shape and calculate their volume under rotation.
$$\frac{1}{3}\pi(2^2)(2)+\pi\int_2^\sqrt{8} (8-x^2)\ \mathrm dx=13.88 \text{ unit}^3$$
I didn't see anything wrong. Can somebody explain this to me?

Just because the shaded area is half that of the quarter-circle doesn't mean that the resulting volume is also half that of the hemisphere! When rotated around the $x$-axis, the shaded region, being closer to the axis, will produce a smaller volume than the unshaded region. This is analogous to how the circumference around a point is greater the further away it is from the point.
